# Does Postgresql support API calls?

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way to know the version of Postgresql using API?

```
Example:  192.168.10.10:5432/getversion
```

(or)

Are there any API which could get some response from Postgresql when I hit

```
Example:  192.168.10.10:5432/gethomepage
```

Kindly let me know whether API calls are supported by Postgres

Comment: Yes, the API is called SQL

Answer (score 1):

There are some open source tools out there that turn postgresql into REST API like:

- [postgREST](https://postgrest.org)
- [hasura](https://hasura.io/)